# How can I setup multiple database(different) connection on the same Rails environment in mongoid.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

(i.e Some Models will use default DB and others will use the second DB when explicitly defined in the model).

I couldn't find any latest references for this.
I wanted to know if something similar mentioned below is possible.

mongoid.yml

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <%=ENV['DEFAULT_DB']%>
    mongo_db:
      uri: <%=ENV['SECOND_DB']%>
```

graph_metric.rb

```
class GraphMetric
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  #Connects to default

  field :timestamp, type: DateTime

end
```

system_metric.rb

```
class SystemMetric
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  #Connect to mongo_db
   some method to establish_connection

  field :timestamp, type: DateTime

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will `store_in` `client` solve the problem for you? 
(see https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#storage)

Answer (score 0):

This Worked.

mongoid.yml

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <%=ENV['DEFAULT_DB']%>
    mongo_db:
      uri: <%=ENV['SECOND_DB']%>
```

graph_metric.rb

```
class GraphMetric
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  #Connects to default

  field :timestamp, type: DateTime

end
```

system_metric.rb

```
class SystemMetric
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  #Connect to mongo_db
   store_in client: :mongo_db

  field :timestamp, type: DateTime

end
```